# Can I modify Capybara page bodies before the browser receives it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a Rails application with Capybara for feature specs. I have some code that results in a url like this `/Users/brandoncc/dev/app/public/uploads/...`. This is a special circumstance in the test environment. I need to modify the response body before the browser gets it. Is that possible? I need to cut off the `/Users/brandoncc/dev/app/public` from image urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options here - the top 3 are probably

1. A programmable proxy like puffing-billy
2. Write a rack middleware class and specify to use it in your config/environments/test.rb via `config.middleware.use=`
3. Write a rack app to wrap the app under test which modifies the responses before returning them and assign that to Capybara.app

Any of those approaches should do what you want, but you may be better off just figuring out why the code is putting full paths in the URLs and fix it to use something like the rails asset helpers instead.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I actually know why it does it, it has to do with carrierwave and not processing the files. I ended up wrapping the capybara lines which raise a 404 in a method called `#ignore_missing_images`' block that ignores 404's for .jpg files. I do agree that your options are probably my other options though. Thanks again!